# String a[] = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"); in java

Tags: java

I am confuse in the logic behind the code `(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")`
it is separating numbers and alphabets like input String `abc12dc23` then it  is spliting it as output `abc 12 dc 23`.

I just want the explanation how the above code is working?

Comment: Ok, you're confused. And what's the question?

Comment: What you're looking at there is a "regular expression" or "regex".  See the [javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or just Google either of those terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex:

```
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

matches 2 kinds of patterns, as suggested by the `|` character:

This pattern:

```
(?<=\D)(?=\d)
```

and this pattern:

```
(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

The former looks for a position in the string where there is a non-digit (`\D`) character before that position and a digit (`\d`) after it. The latter looks for a position where the reverse happens, a digit before and a non-digit after.

To say this in a more abstract way, the regex is looking for *digit-non-digit boundaries*.

The split method looks for all occurrences of the pattern and splits the string when it finds one.